# find length of array like Object {SCHEME_NO: Array[1], REG_CODE: Array[0], REG_NAME: Array[0], STAT_NAME: Array[0]}

Tags: javascript

Object {SCHEME_NO: Array[1], REG_CODE: Array[0], REG_NAME: Array[0], STAT_NAME: Array[0]}

find length of perticular array using javascript.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you clarify what your question is, what you have already tried and give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

To find the **length of an array** in JavaScript, use the array's [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property.

If you want to **count the number of keys in the object** in your example, you have to retrieve an array with the object's keys first with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(yourObject).length
```